# Installing ROR in windows from 7-Zip Archive

Tags: ruby-on-rails, windows, installation

I have extracted the archive . and I have set the path ..

Now in command line , when I give `ruby -v` it gives 2.00p247 and `gem-v` gives 2.0.3 .
but when I try to give the following command `gem install rails` , I am getting the following error

```
ERROR:     Error installing rails:
              The 'atomic' native gem requires installed build tools.

Please update your path to incluide build tools or download the Devkit from 'http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads' and follow the instructions at 'http://github.com/onclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit' ..
```

so my questions is . Is it possible to install rails now without installing the development kit as it is given after `or` . If yes how to update the path to include build tools .

Comment: The easiest method is to use [Rails Installer](http://railsinstaller.org/en). Is there some reason you cant?

Comment: I want to try it from archives , by the way is DevKit mandatory to even install rails to run an existing app